# VS 2015 SSIS Change target Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, configuration

I've created a package in VS 2015 which works. However, when I try to deploy it to my 2014 SQL Server the C# Scripts are causing a problem (they are C# 2015). 
I've looked all over to try and find how to change the target version, and everywhere says to click on the projects properties, go to to the Configuration Properties tab and change the target under general setting.
Unfortunately I don't have a general settings under the Configuration Properties Tab.
Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: What does "causing a problem" mean? Do you get an error message? Sharing that is kind of crucial in you getting help.

Comment: You're in the Solution Property page, not the Project Property page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how you got to the screen in your picture, but you need to do it this way:

Make sure you have an SSIS Package from the Project you want to deploy open in an active window.

In the menu bar:   Project > {Your Project Name} Properties...

Should open a dialog like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tab - this is exactly what I was looking for.